# Navigate to parent of parent stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have this scenario where i have a `StackNavigator` nested in a `TabNavigator` nested in another `StackNavigator`.

```
const TabOneStack = StackNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  ScreenB: { screen: ScreenB }
});

const MainTabs = TabNavigator({
  TabOne: { screen: TabOneStack },
  TabTwo: { screen: TabTwoStack }
});

const Root = StackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  MainTabs: { screen: MainTabs }
});
```

Everything works but i cant figure out how to navigate for example from `ScreenA` back to the Home screen in the root `StackNavigator`.
After the `HomeScreen` the User navigates directly to ScreenA.
The back button in the header in ScreenA works fine and brings me back to Home but need a way to have a button that brings me back to the HomeScreen.
`this.props.navigation.goBack()` does not work unfortunately.

i also tried

```
const backAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'HomeScreen'})
  ]
});    
this.props.navigation.dispatch(backAction));
```

but i get:

**There is no route defined for key HomeScreen. Must be one of: 'ScreenA', 'ScreenB'.**

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To traverse from child `StackNavigator` back to parent `StackNavigator`, do:

```js
class ScreenA extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<Button onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch({type: 'Navigation/BACK'});
        }} title='ScreenA. back to Home' />);
    }
}
```

`this.props.navigation.dispatch()` with `'Navigation/BACK'` works exactly the same as the top-most back button.
It differs from `goBack()` by apply parent-child stack traversing, while `goBack()` does not.

### Result:

[image]

And note @Jigar's answer is also correct, it's just a shorthand notation of mine. The key is to pass `null` argument into `goBack()`. It won't work without that.

```js
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```

Comment: i wish you were right. for some reason it just doesn't do anything in my case. its just frustrating to see the back button working fine but not being able to make a simple button work the same way.

Comment: I copy paste your simple code, make some changes, and have it works. That's how I get my screenshot. If that's not work for you, maybe you can update your question?

Comment: thanks again for checking on this. i will update my question and let you know.

Comment: ok so i figured it out while i was trying to prove the case. i was unnecessarily nesting a stack inside a component i didnt need which for some reason was messing up the routing and navigation. thx for your help!

Answer (score 3):

In the new react native version we use 'StackActions' for this case: 
[StackActions reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset)

the 'key' parameter in this case is the key to solve this problem. Usually we manage the stack like this:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ScreenA' })],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

but StackActions object has another option and its: '**key**' - its an optional string or null - If set, the navigator with the given key will reset. If **null**, the **root navigator will reset**.

So in this case, to reset back to root and navigate to some screen inside it -> in your case from 'ScreenA' to 'HomeScreen' - you should write:

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(
        StackActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          key:null,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              routeName: 'HomeScreen'
            })
          ]
        })
      );
```

Notice, in this new version we no longer use 'NavigationActions' to reset the stack, only 'StackActions'.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```

Comment: this was one of the first things i tried. unfortunately this doesn't work at all.

Comment: @aschmid00 i was stuck on this too but goBack(null)  will pop each route one by one

Answer (score 1):

In v6 you can use something like this:

```
navigation.getParent()?.navigate('Home')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's should working fine by using this:

Change this:

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(backAction));
```

to

```
this.navigator.dispatch(backAction);
```

Also in your render

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Root
        ref={(nav) => {
          this.navigator = nav;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: `this.navigator` is not a function. also what is `<Root />`?

Comment: maybe you meant `this.props.dispatch`? that doesnt work either unfortunately.

Comment: <Root /> is your const Root or your top navigator, did you try the code for the render above? this.navigator should work I think. You can check this issue https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1127